# Making user profiles publicly accessible in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

How can I make user profiles publicly available to anonymous users and search engine bots accessing my website?

Details: User profiles are not publicly accessible by default. Without being logged in to Drupal, if you try to access `/user/123` for example, you get the `You are not authorized to access this page` error message. I want to display the user profile details instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to `/admin/people/permissions`, scroll to the bottom of the page and turn on all check boxes for the `View user profiles` permission.

Comment: I know this sounds simple, but I wasted 30 minutes searching for an answer on Google and here and then decided to fiddle around permissions and found the answer. Hopefully this will save others time in the future.